# Using recursion to multiply elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am writing a program that will multiply the elements in a 2D array with elements in the following rows. I have a recursive method that first iterates through every row of the 2D array, beginning with the second row (array[1][]), finds where there is an array value other than 0 and then takes that value and multiplies it with the recursive call to run the function on the next row of the array. My problem is that when I run the function and pass in 1, 2, and a 3x3 array as the parameters, where array contains 2 in both array[1][2] and array[2][0], a 0 is returned from the function when I expected a 4. I thought that (slopeArray[current][i]), which is 2, should be multiplied with the base case, which should also be 2. Writing everything out by hand, it looked like it should return a 4.

```
int total(int current, int totalCont, int array[3][3]){

  //find the elements in the array that do not contain 0                      
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
   if(array[current][i] != 0){

      //base case                                                                              
      if(current == totalCont){
        return array[current][i];
      }

      //recursive case                                                                         
      else{
        (array[current][i]) * (total(current+1, totalCont, array));

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't `return` anything for `else` case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `return` to the `else`:

```
return array[current][i] * total(current+1, totalCont, array);
^^^^^^
```

The logic of your function is not entirely clear to me. Did you also mean to modify the array?

Comment: No, just access the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have neither `return` nor assignment in the `else` branch. In fact, your function simply ignores the result of multiplication (it is not used anywhere).

Simply adding `return` won't solve the problem though as you probably want to have all three rows being multiplied.